# Set up a proxy on a remote Linux server?

Tags: macos, mac, proxy, socks-proxy

In order to watch Hulu and other sites which are not available in my region (Canada). I would like to set up my own proxy server in the USA on a [Linode](http://www.linode.com/) for my Macbook running Mac OS X. On my Macbook, I would like to set up the proxy server in the OS, instead of the browser so all apps use it. I believe Mac OS X supports HTTP and SOCKS proxies. What type of proxy should I use, and what server software should I use on the Linux machine?

Answer (score 1):

If I was going to do this, I would look into using [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) as a proxy.

But I'm far too honest to do that sort of thing so I don't really know how to go about it...

Comment: "... but you didn't hear *me* say that..."